# Table thead color checkbox check/Uncheck

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, colors, html-table

I have short issue about checkbox all with the table. I no want change color the first thead tr, how remove the color from the header?

I paste the code and I use only Javascript pure.

```
function allpart(chk){
    var parent = chk.parentNode.parentNode;
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var chkpart = document.getElementById('idpart');
    if(chk.checked){
        for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
            if(checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox'){
                checkboxes[i].checked = true;
                checkboxes[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.background = "#CC0000";
                checkboxes[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.color = "#FFF";
            }
        }
    }else{
        for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
            if(checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox'){
                checkboxes[i].checked = false;
                checkboxes[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.background = "";
                checkboxes[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.color = "";   
            }
        }
    }
```

Via html

```html
<table align="center" width="540px" class="tbcuadro">
<thead>
 <tr>
 <th width="5%"><input name="idpart[]" id="idpart" type="checkbox" onclick="allpart(this);"></th>
 <th width="75%" align="center">NAME</th>
 <th width="20%" align="center">NUMBER</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
    <td width="5%"><input name="idpart" type='checkbox'></td>
    <td width="75%">row 1</td>
    <td width="20%">row 2</td>    
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td width="5%"><input name="idpart" type='checkbox'></td>
    <td width="75%">row 1</td>
    <td width="20%">row 2</td>    
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td width="5%"><input name="idpart" type='checkbox'></td>
    <td width="75%">row 1</td>
    <td width="20%">row 2</td>    
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you add your html\

Comment: Why are you starting at line 2?

Comment: I corrected I have not noticed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of code will remove `color` and `background` of all `th`s.

```
var th = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
  for (var i = 0; i < th.length; i++) {
  th[i].style.color = "black";
  th[i].style.background = "white";
}
```

Also this part of code I think is wrong. I change the start index from **2** to **0**

```
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  if (checkboxes[i].type == "checkbox") {
    checkboxes[i].checked = false;
    checkboxes[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.background = "";
    checkboxes[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.color = "";
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you

```js
function allpart(chk) {
  var parent = chk.parentNode.parentNode;
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  var chkpart = document.getElementById("idpart");
  if (chk.checked) {
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      if (checkboxes[i].type == "checkbox") {
        checkboxes[i].checked = true;
        checkboxes[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.background = "#CC0000";
        checkboxes[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.color = "#FFF";
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      if (checkboxes[i].type == "checkbox") {
        checkboxes[i].checked = false;
        checkboxes[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.background = "";
        checkboxes[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.color = "";
      }
    }
  }
  var th = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
  for (var i = 0; i < th.length; i++) {
    th[i].style.color = "black";
    th[i].style.background = "white";
  }
}
```

```html
<table align="center" width="540px" class="tbcuadro">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="5%"><input name="idpart[]" id="idpart" type="checkbox" onclick="allpart(this)"></th>
      <th width="75%" align="center">NAME</th>
      <th width="20%" align="center">NUMBER</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="5%"><input name="idpart" type='checkbox'></td>
      <td width="75%">row 1</td>
      <td width="20%">row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="5%"><input name="idpart" type='checkbox'></td>
      <td width="75%">row 1</td>
      <td width="20%">row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="5%"><input name="idpart" type='checkbox'></td>
      <td width="75%">row 1</td>
      <td width="20%">row 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks you Saaed!. I learn the use of the stackoverflow platform.

Comment: Your welcome. You can accept the answer if it is true. Good luck. And I suggest you to read this [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) @Kais

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional based on thead or tbody to set the color. e.g. if `checkboxes[i].parent("tbody").is("tbody")` then set the color.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the color from the header don't write:

```
checkboxes[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.background = "";
```

write just:

```
checkboxes[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.background = "transparent";
```